# Total height of a binary search tree

Tags: c++, recursion, height, binary-search-tree

I am working on building a Binary Search Tree and I want to create a function that records the height of each node and sums it. I am trying to use recursion.

For me, the difficulty lies in assigning a height to each node, and then going back and summing it up. Unless I can assign and record the height in one pass? Thanks in advance.

edit: Final code to show what worked for me for anyone who will look at this in the future. Thanks for the help guys.

```
BST.h

    int totalheight(node);
    int getHeight(node);

    class BST {
    Node root;
    public:
       BST { root = NULL; }
       int totalheight()
       { return ::totalheight(root);
    };


BST.cpp

int totalHeight(BSTNode* node)
{
   if (node == NULL)
      return -1;

   int leftHeight = getheight(node->left);
   int rightHeight = getheight(node->right);
   int totalheight = 1 + leftHeight + rightHeight; // +1 to count the root

   return totalheight;
} 

int getheight(BSTNode* node)
{
   if (node == NULL)
      return 0;

      return 1 + max(getheight(node->left), getheight(node->right)); 
}

main.cpp

    int main() {
       BST tree; // and various inserts

       tree.totalheight();
    } // main
```

Comment: Can you sort out the code a bit? `totalheight()` without parameters, `totalheigh(BSTNode*)`, `findheight()`, `getheight()` ... it's a bit chaotic.

Comment: It looks like you're mainly having naming and syntax problems and forgetting a `+ 1` in a strategic place.

Comment: Fixed, see above. I included my header file to see how I'm calling it from main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is here:

```
int myheight = max(leftheight, rightheight);
```

It should be:

```
int myheight = max(leftheight, rightheight) + 1;
```

You need the one to accound for this nodes height. Also in the code shown to recurse `findHeight` should be `getHeight`.

Here is an overall function:

```
int getheight(BSTNode* node)
{
    if (node == null)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1 + max(getHeight(node->left), getHeight(node->right)); 
} // getheight
```

Comment: I thought the same at first about handling the case where only left or right is NULL but not both, but technically it was already handled.  The first if check returns -1 and the max() call "filters" that out.  This is also assuming "findHeight" is suppose to be "getHeight".

Comment: Right, I fixed my code a little. We don't need to know this mysterious `findHeight` to be able to compute the height.

Comment: Sorry, I renamed findHeight to getHeight and forgot to edit it in my recursion. Thanks.

Comment: @Dalkurac If this answer solved the issues, dont forget to accept the answer.

Comment: The issue now lies in it not returning an int in my main function. Lemme work on it and if I can't fix it I'll post what I have.

Comment: just put a `return 0;` at the end.

Comment: also if it is unrelated to this question, you can make a new one.